# Macro: activate "automatic caluclation" when opening an excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

How to activate the option " automatic calculation" when directly after opening an excel workbook with a macro?

Comment: Record a macro and manually change the options to 'automatic calculation'. Stop the macro - copy the code there into the Workbook - Open sub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the VB Editor (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and right click `ThisWorkbook` (under Microsoft Excel Objects) --> View Code.

This area handles the workbook event code.

Paste in the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

This just changes the Excel settings to make calculation automatic.  If you want to actually calculate the workbook on open you can do that as well like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'Change calculation setting to automatic
        Application.Calculate 'Perform workbook calculations
End Sub
```